# Mongodb version 3.6.2 can't restart after authentication enabled

Tags: mongodb

I have installed MongoDB 3.6.2 on a server with Ubuntu Server 16.04.
After installation all works fine. Now i need to enable auth on MongoDB and I have seen the guide and i have set my mongod.conf whit securety: authentication: enabled, this my conf file:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

securety:
  authorization: enabled



#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Now, I'm trying to restart MongoDB with `sudo systemtcl restart` but when I run status command the MongoDB status is failed and receive this error:

```
 mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since gio 2018-01-25 13:02:23 CET; 2s ago
 Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Process: 1409 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited
 Main PID: 1409 (code=exited, status=2
```

If I comment the security mode the status comeback to active.

Comment: Can you share error message you're getting, when you restart mongodb service.

Comment: I have updated my post with the error code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
security:
   authorization: enabled
```

instead of

```
securety:
  authorization: enabled
```